# Issue with Angular Forms : AbstractControl vs FormControl

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

When I am trying to use a form with controls I am getting this error.

```
 Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 
'FormControl': registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange, _applyFormState
```

Form Code

```
  this.checkoutForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+[a-zA-Z]$')]],
      lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+[a-zA-Z]$')]],
      phoneNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]+')]],
      address: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]],
      pinCode: ['', Validators.required]
    });
```

html

```
<input type="text" 
name="firstName"
[formControl]="checkoutForm.controls['firstName']" 
value="" 
placeholder="" 
autocomplete="off"      
>
```

Comment: <strike>use a getter and cast to FormControl i.e. `return checkoutForm.controls['firstName'] as FormControl`</strike>

Comment: @AndrewAllen won't change anything

Comment: i think so you are direct access without formgroup in html so that's why its generate error so please try with fromgroup and formcontrolname.check this link  [angular] https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup with the registercontrol

Comment: Any specific reason why you are not using `formControlName`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create reactive forms, you're supposed to use the form itself, not the controls of it.

if you just use the controls, separately, then what's the point of having a form ?

```
<form [formGroup]="checkoutForm">
  <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
</form>
```

Comment: Really it's the best aproach, but if you want to use [formControl] use `[formControl]="checkoutForm.get('firstName')"`

Comment: Oh nice. I didn't know .get returns a FormControl so I already went and made a pipe. 
 :D

`transform(id: string, form: FormGroup): FormControl { return form.controls[id] as FormControl; }`

Comment: But using the cast cause a code-smell in the unit testing. How do you want to fix it?

Answer (score -2):

This works for me. i.e. `$any()`

```
  <ion-checkbox
      
        [formControl]="$any(fc)"
      
        (ionChange)="changeCheckbox()"
      >
```